# Pie Chart labels overlapping

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

No matter what I do, I can not seem to find code to ensure the labels of my Pie chart, do not overlap the Pie chart OR other labels.

I've entered `geom_text_repel` and adjusted `vjust` `size` `force` `x` in various ways and nothing works.  It works on some charts, and other charts it does not.
[image: pie chart]

````
       ---
title: "Untitled"
date: "August 14, 2019"
output: html_document
---

```{r eval = TRUE, echo = FALSE, results = "asis", warning = FALSE,  message = FALSE, fig.height = 6.25, fig.width = 12}

library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
library(RODBC)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(treemapify)
library(devtools)
library(digest)
library(plotly)
library(shiny)
library(ggrepel)
library(expss)

rptyear <- 2018
colours <- c("A" = "royalblue3", "B" = "red", "C" = "gold", "D" = "green4")

Category <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

premiumtable <- cbind(rep(c("A","B","C","D"),11), c(rep(2009,4),rep(2010,4),rep(2011,4),rep(2012,4),rep(2013,4),rep(2014,4),rep(2015, 4), rep(2016,4), rep(2017,4), rep(2018,4),rep(2019,4)), as.numeric(c(13223284, 3379574,721217, 2272843,14946074,4274769, 753797,2655032, 15997384, 4952687, 722556,3035566,16244348,5541543,887109,3299966,15841630,6303443,1101696,3751892,14993295, 6993626,1312650,4158196,13946038, 7081457,1317428,4711389, 12800640, 6923012, 1345159, 4911780, 12314663, 6449919, 1395973,5004046,12612704,6968110,1507382,5745079,15311213,8958588,1849069,6819488)))
colnames(premiumtable) <- c("Var1", "Var2", "Freq")
      currentPrem <- filter(as.data.table(premiumtable), Var2 == rptyear, Freq != 0)
      prempie <- ggplot(currentPrem, aes(x="", y = as.numeric(currentPrem$Freq), fill= Var1)) 
      prempie <- prempie + geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity", colour = "black") 
      prempie <- prempie + ggtitle(paste0("YTD Numbers:")) + coord_polar("y", start = 0) 
      prempie <- prempie + scale_fill_manual(values = colours)  
      prempie <- prempie + theme_void()+ theme(plot.title = element_text(face = "bold", size = 20, hjust = .5), legend.position = "none",  axis.title=element_text(size=20), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.title.x = element_blank())
      prempie <- prempie +  geom_text_repel(mapping = aes(label = paste0(Var1, "\n $",prettyNum(round(as.numeric(currentPrem$Freq)/1000), big.mark = ",")) , x =  2),position = position_stack( vjust = .5), size = 6, force = 5,direction = "both",  segment.size = 0)
```
````

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: okay, I've added the data and changed the picture to reflect the data, but the same code posted above, works with different data (ie doesn't have overlapping) but sometimes it does.  It's the same "var1" and "var2" every time, just different "Freq".

Comment: This is still far from being reproducible. For example, `rptyear` in your filter statement is not defined, `colours` in your scale_fill_manual is not defined. The function `geom_text_repel` is not from a base library so you need a `library()` call for that library. It's also much easier if you provide your data as R code (i.e. using dput). Can you copy paste the code provided into a fresh R session and run it without errors? Then it is reproducible.

Comment: there, it is good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for providing the working data/code. If you are open to using the package `plotly` it is quite good at producing pie charts right out of the box, and requires less fiddling about than ggplot. Here is an example with your data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

#
rptyear <- 2018
colours <- c("A" = "royalblue3", "B" = "red", "C" = "gold", "D" = "green4")

# data
premiumtable <- data.frame(Var1 = rep(c("A","B","C","D"),11),
                           Var2 = c(rep(2009,4),rep(2010,4),rep(2011,4),rep(2012,4),rep(2013,4),rep(2014,4),rep(2015, 4),rep(2016,4), rep(2017,4),rep(2018,4),rep(2019,4)),
                           Freq = as.numeric(c(13223284, 3379574,721217, 2272843,14946074,4274769, 753797,2655032, 15997384, 4952687, 722556,3035566,16244348,5541543,887109,3299966,15841630,6303443,1101696,3751892,14993295, 6993626,1312650,4158196,13946038, 7081457,1317428,4711389, 12800640, 6923012, 1345159, 4911780, 12314663, 6449919, 1395973,5004046,12612704,6968110,1507382,5745079,15311213,8958588,1849069,6819488)))

# prepare plot data
currentPrem <-   
  premiumtable %>% 
  filter(Var2 == rptyear, Freq != 0) %>% 
  mutate(Freq = as.numeric(Freq))

# create plot labels
labels = paste0(currentPrem$Var1, "\n $",prettyNum(round(as.numeric(currentPrem$Freq)/1000), big.mark = ","))

# create plot
plot_ly(currentPrem,
        labels = ~labels,
        values = ~Freq, type = 'pie',
        textposition = 'outside',
        textinfo = 'label',
        colors = colours) %>%
  layout(title = paste("YTD Numbers:", rptyear),
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         showlegend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm definitely open, I will test this out tomorrow and see how it goes! thanks :)

Comment: Hi, this works well! I just need to know how to print it with r markdown and knitr,  I tried to assign the graph to variable prempie like in  my example and went print(prempie, floating = FALSE) and it doesn't show up.  I'm assuming it's an easy fix but some light researching got me nowhere, but I'll continue to search while I wait for a response

Comment: Added: I am knitting to PDF

Comment: Your original code had the output as html. If you want the output as PDF you can either use `export()` to write to disk (png, pdf, etc), then `knitr::include_graphics()` or you can use the package `webshot`. I'd ask this as a new question if you need more detail.